# How should I architect my Silverlight Application?

Tags: silverlight, architecture

So far I have been creating Silverlight apps with all logic crunched into a single xap file. But as the application grows in size, 
I seriously think I should break my Silverlight application into smaller multiple independent applications.

I would like to know how others solve this increasing size problem??

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is it loading too slowly?

Comment: @ Ben M. Yes it's loading too slowly. Besides, i want to know another way to architect it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're looking to make some changes to your application, by refactoring it and splitting out parts, consider all of these.

#### Custom controls get their own control assembly

Definitely create control assemblies for any custom controls you develop. Not only do you get the benefit of self-contained controls, and optional use in your current and future projects, you can

- take advantage of default control styles
- use the cached assembly feature with them
- share components with other projects
- invest in your core code and controls, instead of investing in cleaning up application logic (if you're using static or style analysis, for instance) - spend your time where it will make the most impact

#### Consider dynamically loading new assemblies

There are some [methods available for dynamically loading additional code](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2008/04/14/10330.aspx) into your app domain, it may be possible to abstract out less-often used parts of your app, and use this to load in those components. This is a more complex and involved app, but it can improve start-up performance.

It'll take time to split out the code into other assemblies when you're looking at a large application, and testing it can be a challenge. But you can end up with "sub-pages" and parts of your app being loaded only as needed.

Taking the time to design a system to load in new functionality and parts of your app, and architecting this framework, can take time to do right. This typically is using AssemblyPart to load a new assembly that you can reflect into and instantiate new objects from.

#### Merged Resource Dictionaries

[Resource dictionaries](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Merged-Resource-Dictionaries-in-Silverlight-3.aspx) can allow you to store styles, control templates, and other resources outside of pages, and outside of your App.xaml.

#### Cached Assemblies

Once you move to Silverlight 3, you can use the [cached assemblies feature](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/07/13/silverlight-3-cached-assembly-feature.aspx) to store individual assemblies outside your .Xap, alongside, on your server - and as a bonus, those assemblies will be cached on the machine for quite some time.

#### A resource diet

Are you really using all of your graphic assets, XAML, controls, string resources, etc., that are stored inside your XAP file? Audit it from time-to-time and make sure you're getting the most bang for your byte.

#### A splash screen

If you're simply trying to improve the performance (download time) for your application initially, consider creating a splash screen. The [Silverlight Toolkit samples](http://silverlight.net/samples/sl3/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html) have one - it's a simple Silverlight page that will load and display while your .Xap downloads.

#### Remote graphics

Instead of including image resources right inside your application/XAP, move your images to your CDN or server, so they can be loaded only as needed. This is often a nice and quick win.

#### Simplify your app

Make sure you actually need it to be XAML-heavy, graphic-heavy, etc. Maybe it can be simplified!

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeff for your wealthy answer. I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 3):

You should distribute your Silverlight modules using PRISM or MEF frameworks.

Visit http://mef.codeplex.com/